# sympy assumptions not appearing to work properly

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to define a symbol as real and positive to weed out irrelevant roots (i.e. the four roots it gives me should be reduced to two. How do I accomplish this?

```
import sympy as sp
w=sp.Symbol('w',positive=True,real=True)
J2,k=sp.symbols('J2 k')
J=sp.Matrix([[3,0],[0,1]]) #need to be defined as sp.Matrix in order for det() functiont to work
K=sp.Matrix([[2,-1],[-1,1]])

J=J2*J
K=k*K
x=-w**2*J+K
xx=x.det()
ww=sp.solve(xx,w)
ww
```

output:

```
[-sqrt(6)*sqrt(-sqrt(13)*k/J2 + 5*k/J2)/6,
 sqrt(6)*sqrt(-sqrt(13)*k/J2 + 5*k/J2)/6,
 -sqrt(6)*sqrt(sqrt(13)*k/J2 + 5*k/J2)/6,
 sqrt(6)*sqrt(sqrt(13)*k/J2 + 5*k/J2)/6]
```

You can see visually that for w = real, positive, items 1 and 3 in this list should be eliminated

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any assumptions on `J2` or `k` so there's no way for sympy to know if any of the roots is positive or negative or even real:

If you do

```
J2, k = sp.symbols('J2, k', positive=True)
```

Then you can get:

```
In [26]: ww
Out[26]: 
⎡     ______________       _____________⎤
⎢√6⋅╲╱ -√13⋅k + 5⋅k   √6⋅╲╱ √13⋅k + 5⋅k ⎥
⎢───────────────────, ──────────────────⎥
⎢          ____                ____     ⎥
⎣      6⋅╲╱ J₂             6⋅╲╱ J₂      ⎦
```